# Use table with footnotes and colored cells

Tags: tables, color, footnotes

Is it possible to have a LaTEX document that contains both a table with footnotes and colored cells? The package `colortbl` seems to cause problems if `savenotes` is used somewhere in the document.
Does a workaround exist for that?

Code:

```
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{savenotes}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Table}

  \begin{tabular}{l}
     Header \\
     Row 1 \\ 
     Row 2\footnote{Footnote.} \\
  \end{tabular}

  \label{Tbl_1}
\end{table}
\end{savenotes}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example. Can't you just use the standard way to get footnotes here? i.e. Make the mark and create the footnote outside?

Comment: package footnote is incompatible with color/xcolor due to a bug. You can try recent package [footnotehyper](http://ww.ctan.org/pkg/footnotehyper), but use of hyperref is then more or less mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the `tablefootnote` command from the package of the same name works well and is not in conflict with `colortbl`.

Answer (score 1):

Migrated from comment:

package footnote is incompatible with color/xcolor due to a bug. You can try recent package [footnotehyper](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnotehyper), but use of hyperref is then more or less mandatory.

edit: I copied pasted code snippet from OP which is not a mwe, not having time then nor now to really add the missing pieces. To get something more realistic use for example:

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}[0pt]}l|}
```

which seems to work ok but I don't modify the image.

**note**: package footnote as used below via footnotehyper has NO facilities to handle correctly footnotes from floating objects like tables. It will work sort of.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{footnotehyper}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{savenotes}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Table}

  \begin{tabular}{l}
     Header \\
     Row 1 \\ 
     Row 2\footnote{Footnote.} \\
  \end{tabular}

  \label{Tbl_1}
\end{table}
\end{savenotes}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

and at bottom of page

[image]